# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined DemoNew.html:51 (anonymous function)

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JQuery and I face the Uncaught ReferenceError. To be more specific, here is my code with the tags included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
 };
</script>
```

I also get the following error:

```
GET file:///C:/Users/Stelios/Desktop/SSG/Learning/jquery.js
```

Comment: just download the missing jQuery library (either jquery-1.10.2.min.js or jquery-1.10.2.js) from this page: http://www.jquery.com/download to your `SSG/Learning` directory and rename it to `jquery.js`

Comment: Thanks Stano! Fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

The filename or path to your jQuery file is probably wrong, try using Google's version instead:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your jquery.js file in DemoNew.html folder, Then try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Or you can use absolute addressing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///c:/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ABFORCE! Fixed now!